# Elementary OS is slow and unstable

Tags: laptop

I've installed Elementary OS for web development and android development. I usually work with Vscode, terminal and multiple chrome tabs opened. I'm pretty sure that my laptop can handle it. I face lags in vscode and in chrome. Android Studio is also pretty lagging.

Spec:
8gb Ram,
AMD A10 processor,
Dedicated Graphics. AMD 530 Graphics 2gb,
Installed OS on SSD.
Dual boot with Windows 10

Comment: Open terminal, type uname -a then type sudo update-initramfs -u and provide results.

Comment: ```uname -a
Linux vsskamal 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-62-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdb6
I: (UUID=7742a678-cc87-4fd7-bda8-8cce92408272)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.```

Comment: Check which GPU is in use. See this thread. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16407/how-to-check-which-gpu-is-active-in-linux I am wondering will kernel upgrade to 5.7.7 will solve your problem. I have a tutorial for the kernel update. But first check which GPU is in use and let me know. They provided commands which will let you to check this in terminal.

Comment: `lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] [1002:9874] (rev ca) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`

Comment: Your primary GPU is Radeon and is working. OK. Then the only solution I have is a kernel upgrade.

Comment: Actually, my laptop had 512mb of integrated and 2gb of dedicated graphics card. (Radeon 530). I don't know which card is active. Integrated or dedicated

Comment: Command above shows dedicated.

Comment: Thread about Android Studio in stack overflow: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up)

Comment: Hey! Wifi is fixed and not getting the error on boot. And lagging happening on all the IDE's not just android studio. I thought linux supposed to be faster than windows. Or Elementary os itself slow? Can I change my OS or else?

Comment: Hard to say. Elementary OS is slow according to other distros. You can try Arco Linux instead and check, or Debian. I would rather stay away from Ubuntu, Elementary OS. You can also check Linux Mint. Really have no idea which will work faster. Anyway the link I provided shows that Android Studio is lagging and needs more RAM. Can you put more RAM and check?

Comment: You can try BBQ Linux. https://bbqlinux.org/ See this comparison. https://embeddedinventor.com/best-linux-distro-for-android-development-an-analysis/

Answer (score 1):

**How to upgrade Elementary OS to the newest kernel.**

Install necessary packages

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libncurses-dev bison flex libssl-dev libelf-dev
```

Make directory for kernel

```
sudo mkdir /home/yourusername/Downloads/kernel
```

Download kernel 5.7.8

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/kernel
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.7.8.tar.xz
tar -xf linux-5.7.8.tar.xz
cd linux-5.7.8
cp -v /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make menuconfig
```

Save config and then exit. Use tab button to select first the save button, then, OK, then Exit, and once again exit.

use 4 core/thread - if your processor have 4 cores

```
make -j 4
```

use 8 core/thread - if your processor have 8 cores

```
make -j 8
```

Type in terminal

```
sudo make modules_install 
sudo make install 
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.7.8
```

ignore these errors below, just because those three bin files are not made yet

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_dmcu.bin for module amdgpu
```

Update grub entries and restart the computer

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

After restart open terminal and type, to check the kernel version:

```
uname -mrs
```

to check errors after reboot:

```
sudo journalctl -xb
sudo dmesg
```

Comment: Wifi not working after upate and boot time increased. `W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_dmcu.bin for module amdgpu`

Comment: Ok. You need to install firmware for Wi-Fi adapter. I will provide a tutorial.

Comment: Tutorial for missing Realtek added. Let me know does Wi-Fi work after restart and write about system behavior. Do you still have lags?

Comment: Wifi still not fixed. Yes, I'm having lags while opening new tabs in google chrome, when alt + tab. lags in vs code, and some IDE's. Nothing's changed I guess. Weirdly I'm getting some errors while booting. It takes around 20-30 seconds and it showing this error. https://imgur.com/a/Kg2KUwm after that it showing elementary os symbol. I'm on SSD. I don't know why it's taking that much time.

Comment: Did you install firmware for Wi-Fi? I provided tutorial.

Comment: Can you install Firefox and check does it lag?

Comment: Install Intel microcode:Type in terminal:
sudo apt install intel-microcode
After that restart the computer and check does the ACPI error show.

Comment: Yes, I've installed firmware for wifi like you said. I restarted but wifi not working. Also, firefox is not lagging. but the IDE's that I use are lagging. It's taking delay when I click on any option and coding is also slow. When I install intel-microcode, it showing that i've installed it already

Comment: Can you check what this command will display in terminal?
sudo lshw -C network

Comment: *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: ac:e2:d3:7b:ea:d6
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

Comment: *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d2000000-d200ffff

Comment: *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s16u3
       serial: f2:8d:81:80:ab:25
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.80 link=yes multicast=yes

Comment: What this command shows? sudo lspci | grep -i realtek

Comment: 01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723

Comment: What this command shows? lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
05:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] [1002:6900] (rev 83)

Comment: I provided tutorial: Install Wi-Fi drivers.

Answer (score 1):

**How to install Realtek firmware**

Make directory for Realtek firmware

```
mkdir /home/username/Downloads/rtl
```

Enter directory for Realtek firmware

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/rtl
```

Download  Realtek firmware

```
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw
```

Copy Realtek firmware to proper firmware directory in system

```
sudo cp rtl8168fp-3.fw /lib/firmware/rtl_nic 
sudo cp rtl8125a-3.fw /lib/firmware/rtl_nic
```

Update initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.7.8
```

update GRUB:

```
sudo update-grub
```

check kernel version after reboot:

```
uname -mrs
```

check errors after reboot:

```
sudo journalctl -xb
sudo dmesg
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to install Realtek Wi-Fi drivers manually**

Type in terminal:

```
cd
mkdir /home/username/Downloads/realtek
cd /home/username/Downloads/realtek
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-5.3.0-62
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
sudo chmod +x dkms-install.sh
sudo chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
```

Type to install:

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/realtek/rtl8821ce
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Type to remove if you will have to remove it after the reboot.

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/realtek/rtl8821ce
sudo ./dkms-remove.sh
```

Comment: When I run this cmd sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) I'm getting this errors
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.7.8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.7.8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.7.8'

Comment: Try :
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-5.3.0-62

Comment: sudo ./dkms-install.sh
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20200325
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 already built for kernel 5.7.8/4
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 already installed on kernel 5.7.8/x86_64
Finished running dkms install steps.

Comment: Hah, so you have the module for Wi-Fi already installed and it is not working. Then the only choice is to choose older linux kernel version when GRUB shows after the computer start. And then remove the kernel you previously installed 5.7.8. I will provide a tutorial how to remove it safely.

Also check the swappiness with this command:
sysctl vm.swappiness

How much free memory you have: 
free -h

And the swap size with these two commands:
df -Th /swap
grep -i swap /etc/fstab

Comment: sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.3G        1.7G        737M        270M        4.9G        5.1G
Swap:          4.9G          0B        4.9G
df -Th /swap grep -i swap /etc/fstab
df: /swap: No such file or directory
df: grep: No such file or directory
df: swap: No such file or directory
Filesystem     Type Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb5      ext4   8.2M  489K  7.7M    6% /

Comment: Show only this: 

grep -i swap /etc/fstab

Comment: Added tutorial: How to safely remove 5.7.8 kernel

Answer (score 1):

**How to safely remove 5.7.8 kernel**

```
cd /var/lib/initramfs-tools/
sudo rm -rf 5.7.8
cd /boot
sudo apt --purge remove linux-image-5.7.8
sudo rm -f config-5.7.8
sudo rm -f initrd.img-5.7.8
sudo rm -f System.map-5.7.8
sudo rm -f vmlinuz-5.7.8
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
sudo update-grub
sudo systemctl reboot
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
sudo purge-old-kernels
sudo apt --purge autoremove
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
sudo update-grub
sudo systemctl reboot
```